# BioPython SeqIO fails with Invalid Alphabet found

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, genbank

I am trying to store a GenBank file that could be read by Geneious later.
I found an example how to create the GenBank file [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216225/writing-and-saving-genbank-files-with-biobython-seqio-module)

But now I run into `Alphabet` issues.
I tried all protein classes from the [documentation](https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Alphabet.IUPAC.html), but all fail with the same error:

`TypeError: Invalid alphabet found, <class 'Bio.Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet'>.`

I dont know what else to do here? Using `biopython==1.73`

```
    record = SeqRecord.SeqRecord(
        Seq.Seq("MIRQALAVAALLLAGTAQADGLIDN", alphabet=Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet),
        id="FooBar",
    )

    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w") as genbank:
        SeqIO.write(record, genbank, "genbank")
        pass
```

Comment: You're passing the class `Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet` as argument. You should instantiate it: `Alphabet.ProteinAlphabet()`. Note that the Alphabet module is obsolet in recent versions https://biopython.org/docs/1.75/api/Bio.Alphabet.html#module-Bio.Alphabet

Comment: I think biopython is already over 1.81 version , in anycase pleae have a look at https://biopython.org/wiki/Alphabet History and replacement of Bio.Alphabet